# What is pyspark-cassandra for, now that SparkSQL can use the Cassandra connector?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there something I'm missing or are all the functionalities now available directly?

It seems possible to connect the SparkSQL to Cassandra in the JVM and then use it from Python, without moving everything to Python.

Comment: I have encountered a similar situation for MongoDB and I have now started migrating my codebase to use SparkSQL instead.

Comment: Generally speaking `CassandraRDD` / RDD API provide fine-grained control and some capabilities which simply cannot expressed using `DataFrame` API.